# C++ creating a vector which stores different typenames

Tags: c++, vector, types

I want to create a vector which stores name of data types(int,char,bool,etc)

I am looking for something like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc,char** argv)
{
  vector<typenames> v = {int,float,double,bool};
}
```

Comment: You can not do that in C++ either you use [typeid](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) or, if you want something static, an empty std::tuple or dedicated TypeList<typename...>

Comment: Containers are used to store object of some types not the type itself, may be you could tell more about the problem you're trying to solve ?

Comment: Names or types? Types are not first-class objects in C++, and can only be manipulated at compile-time. You can start with `std::tuple` if you want to store a few of them.

Comment: How about using `std::vector<std::any>` ?

Comment: What do you want this for; what problem were you having where you decided you wanted a vector of types?

Comment: This surely is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What is it you *actually* want to accomplish?

Answer (score 5):

If you have a finite set of types you want to store, you can use [`<variant>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/variant), e.g.

```
#include <variant>

using VarType = std::variant<int, float, double, bool>;
std::vector<VarType> v;

v.push_back(42);

assert(std::holds_alternative<int>(v.front()));
assert(std::get<int>(v.front()) == 42);

v[0] = true;

assert(std::holds_alternative<bool>(v.front()));
assert(std::get<bool>(v.front()));
```

Note that if C++17 is not available, you can go with [Boost variant](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/variant.html).

Answer (score 3):

No. It's not possible. C++ is a statically-typed language, not a dynamic-typed language.  What you can do is have set of enums, for types and put them into `vector`.

```
enum Type
{
    IntType, FloatType, DoubleType, BoolType
};

vector<Type> v;
```

Or you can use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) (C++17).

Your question wasn't clear. Maybe you need `std::pair` or `std::tuple` to keep different items (with a defined number of elements).